# Laravel 5 how to properly use settings variable in my view

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I'm trying to learn laravel since 3 days and i have a little a problem.

In my database i have a table 'settings', which looks like : [image]

I need to use this data in EVERY page that i load. I do something like that for load the data in my view :

```
public function indexFront()
{
    $posts = $this->blog_gestion->indexFront($this->nbrPages);
    $links = str_replace('/?', '?', $posts->render());


    //Here i load my setting
    $setting_gestion = new SettingRepository(new setting());
    $config = $setting_gestion->getSettings('ferulim');


    //Next i pass my setting to my view
    return view('front.blog.index', compact('posts', 'links', 'config'));
}
```

It works but i need to do that in every controller and every function... I think there is an another way for do the same thing :p

Help me !

Comment: I think you're looking for [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers). Also have a look at the section about *Sharing Data With All Views*.

Comment: Not sure if my wife would be ok with this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve that for selected views or all views using View Composers (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers).

First, you need to implement a view composer that does the logic that you want to do for every view:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
  public function boot()
  {
    View::composer('*', function($view) {
      $blog_gestion = ...; // fetch or instantiate your $blog_gestion object          
      $posts = $blog_gestion->indexFront($this->nbrPages);
      $links = str_replace('/?', '?', $posts->render());

      $setting_gestion = new SettingRepository(new setting());
      $config = $setting_gestion->getSettings('ferulim');

      $view->with(compact('posts', 'links', 'config'));
    });
  }

  public function register()
  {
    //
  }
}
```

Next, register your new service provider in **providers** array in your **config/app.php**.

That's it :) Let me know if there are any typos/errors, I haven't had a chance to run the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It works like a charm ;)